# Recovering a Synology Raid 0 from Ubuntu (Healthy drives)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm, raid-0

I am trying to remount a Synology raid 0 with 3x2GB drives. As far as I know, the drives are in healthy condition.

I simply don't have enough space to do a full image of these before I proceed, so I hope more experienced users can assist me. The data is certainly not the most important stuff I have, but naturally it would be great if I could recover it.

Sorry for such a massive post, but I figured it was best to give you as much info as possible.

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

```
#sudo fdisk -l
```

(Just listing my raid drives)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00098445

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           256    4980735    4980480  2,4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       4980736    9175039    4194304    2G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       9437184 3906824351 3897387168  1,8T fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0004a6ce

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           256    4980735    4980480  2,4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       4980736    9175039    4194304    2G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       9437184 3906824351 3897387168  1,8T fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d3273

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1          2048    4982527    4980480  2,4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd2       4982528    9176831    4194304    2G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd3       9437184 3906824351 3897387168  1,8T fd Linux raid autodetect
```

**Then the output of mdstat:**

```
#sudo cat /proc/mdstat
```

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : inactive sdb3[2](S) sda3[0](S) sdd3[1](S)
      5846077648 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: none
```

**Then result of examining the #3 partition on each drive:**

```
#sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda3
```

```
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a55ec236:a21e68d6:880073e6:0767672b
           Name : Rackstation:3
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 29 20:55:08 2017
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3897385088 (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=32 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 97599be0:421d7434:27cf35e3:3738cb20

    Update Time : Wed Dec  6 10:30:37 2017
       Checksum : 971d4c1e - correct
         Events : 2

     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

```
#sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb3
```

```
/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a55ec236:a21e68d6:880073e6:0767672b
           Name : Rackstation:3
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 29 20:55:08 2017
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3897385088 (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=32 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3d7f416b:da7acb4c:db31ee99:2d7c160d

    Update Time : Wed Dec  6 10:30:37 2017
       Checksum : dd1e7607 - correct
         Events : 2

     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

```
#sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdd3
```

```
/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a55ec236:a21e68d6:880073e6:0767672b
           Name : Rackstation:3
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 29 20:55:08 2017
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3897385120 (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a5b79e82:0c39533c:4f4adae0:540dafdf

    Update Time : Sun Oct 29 20:55:08 2017
       Checksum : fe189076 - correct
         Events : 0

     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

mdadm reports that the raid is clean, which is good I guess?

I then followed the advice here: [re-mount-two-old-disk-from-raid0-setup-to-recover-data](https://superuser.com/questions/589206/re-mount-two-old-disk-from-raid0-setup-to-recover-data)

```
 #sudo mount /dev/md127 /mnt/oldData
mount: /mnt/oldData: can't read superblock on /dev/md127.
```

Then googled some more and ran:

```
#sudo mdadm -D /dev/md127
```

```
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : Rackstation:3
           UUID : a55ec236:a21e68d6:880073e6:0767672b
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       51        -        /dev/sdd3
       -       8       19        -        /dev/sdb3
       -       8        3        -        /dev/sda3
```

Can anyone read anything from this? Help is greatly appreciated.